# db evolution, oracle multi line

Tags: playframework-1.x, multiline

I work with play 1.2.5,

I want use the db evolution system with oracle 11g Release 2.

But when I have a multi line request,

```
# --- la table champ pointe directement sur la table categorie (pas de relation n, n )

# --- !Ups

    DROP TABLE CATEGORIE_CHAMP;
    ALTER TABLE CHAMP ADD (ID_CATEGORIE  NUMBER(38));
    ALTER TABLE CHAMP ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CHAMP_CATEGORIE FOREIGN KEY (ID_CATEGORIE) REFERENCES CATEGORIE(ID_CATEGORIE);

# --- !Downs
  CREATE TABLE "CATEGORIE_CHAMP" 
   (    "ID_CATEGORIE" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "ID_CHAMP" NUMBER(38,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "Categorie_Champ PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_CHAMP", "ID_CATEGORIE")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "CATEGORIE_CHAMP_CATEGORIE" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_CATEGORIE")
      REFERENCES "RENTIT"."CATEGORIE" ("ID_CATEGORIE") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "CATEGORIE_CHAMP_CHAMP" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_CHAMP")
      REFERENCES "RENTIT"."CHAMP" ("ID_CHAMP") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

 ALTER TABLE CHAMP DROP COLUMN ID_CATEGORIE;
```

This request don't work and do an issue :

```
ORA-00911: caractère non valide
[ERROR:911, SQLSTATE:22019]
 invalid character. The character is the ;.
```

What is the solution for do a multi line request?

Answer (score 0):

For information I have resolve the issue, I have change the class play.db.SQLSplitter.

I have change the ligne 195 and 196 of :

```
++i;
CharSequence ret = sql.subSequence(prev, i);
```

in :

```
CharSequence ret = sql.subSequence(prev, i);
++i;
```

So the final ; is not used, And the request work.